# Password protect removal of apps on iOS

Tags: ios, applications, security

I have had instances of people deleting my applications (purposedly or unpurposedly) and it's a real annoyance to get them back, plus you lose all of your data. 
Is there a way to password protect the removal of applications, maybe through the use of a Cydia tweak?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for a jailbreak. Simply go into Settings>General>Restrictions and don't allow "Deleting Apps". Restrictions are protected using a password just like your lock passcode (although it can be a different code if you would like).

Comment: I'm not really convinced by this way of doing things: it makes it a lot harder for me to actually delete something when I have to.

Comment: This answers your question exactly. It passcode protects deletions. Making it harder to delete apps is the point of your question and this answer. Why are you "not convinced"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself properly: if I actually need to delete something I'm forced to go in the settings to disable the protection, delete the app and turn the protection back on. It takes a lot of time

Comment: I'm interested in a more granular response here. Basically looking at how to password protect removal of one specific application. Is this possible in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the current or a recent version of iOS such as iOS 13 or 12, you can prevent accidental app deletions by disabling all app deletions via Settings -> Screentime-> Content & Privacy Restrictions -> iTunes & App Store Purchases > Deleting Apps > Don't Allow. If you want this option to be password protected, set a password via Settings -> Screentime-> Content&Privacy Restrictions -> Use Screen Time Passcode.

Answer (score 0):

Erase and supervise the device in [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12), then enroll it in [Jamf Now](https://signup.jamfnow.com/?r=1ef198c760ff4bf0a1aa1e98c98c9233) - first three devices are free forever.  Other MDMs are similar, but Jamf is the easiest and most developed.

With a supervised device, you can then enable various security settings, including disabling the ability to delete apps, among many others.  You could also use Jamf to distribute and remove free apps, or set up an Apple Business Manager account (requires a DUNS number) and manage free and paid content from the App Store and Books Store.

In this way, app management is password protected - but at the login to Jamf, not onboard the device.